# How to copy text from RichTextBox?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a RichTextBox which contains text of subscript & superscript, the problem is that I can't copy the text as it is from the RichTextBox, what I get, is the text without any subscript or superscript as the original text.

I will appreciate it if some point me to the right solution.

Here is my copy code:

```
TextRange copiedTextRange = new TextRange(richTextSourceText.Document.ContentStart, richTextSourceText.Document.ContentEnd);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
copiedTextRange .Save(memoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

Then, here is my paste code:

```
TextRange pastedTextRange;
pastedTextRange= new TextRange(richTextDestinationText.Document.ContentStart, richTextDestinationText.Document.ContentEnd);
            pastedTextRange.Load(memoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

Comment: Do you have same issue with DataFormats.Html?

Comment: what do you mean, did have any similar issues with HTML?

Comment: When you grab the formatted text from the box it is encoded in a particular format.  This is just  the format that is pushed and pulled from the MemoryStream.  In your case you specified DataFormat.Rtf which is RichTextFormat.  You could try changing that to DataFormat.Html. (pastedTextRange.Load(memoryStream, DataFormats.Html); )

Comment: If you try this don't forget to change Save AND Load lines to DataFormat.Html ;-)

Comment: I have tried to use Html format but I get the following exception 'HTML Format' data format not supported.